# How to increment and find/replace number using sed or perl

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a git tag named "a_tag-30" and I want find the last tag and increment it by 1 using a sed or perl expression, so the result will be "a_tag-31". Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What happens if it is 39?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of thing is easiest using a combination of utilities in bash. For example:

```
echo "a_tag-$(($(git tag --list 'a_tag-*' 
    | sed -e 's/^.*-\([0-9]*\)/\1/'  
    | sort -nr
    | head -1) + 1))" > output
```

This will write the new tag to `output`.

As well as having a prefix "a_tag", It assumes all your tags end in a dash followed by a number.

Comment: If it's not in the input, how do you it then? I have a list of tags and last tag has number 30, and I want to increment it with 1. So it will be tag-31.

Comment: I modified the command to use the git command to produce the list of tags.

Comment: No problem. As well as accepting an answer, you can also up-vote any and all answers that were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Following git command gets all the tags matching the pattern "a_tag-*" sorted in descending order via "-taggerdate" key.

`git tag --list 'a_tag-*' --sort=-taggerdate | head -1 | awk -F- '{print "a_tag-" $NF+1}'`

Then the first line is fed to the awk command where "-" used as a field separator.
Hence $NF positional parameter (i.e. NF means Number of Fields and it is a predefined variable in awk) holds the value of last field.

Finally the new tag value is printed by incrementing $NF by 1.